# Scanner colour cast - ICC ignored

Tags: 19.10, scanner, color-management, icc

I have an Epson ET2750 all in one and whilst the scanner works fine with Ubuntu, it always scans with a blue colour cast. Scanner to the memory card in the printer works correctly so I know it's Ubuntu.

I have used the scanner calibration built into Ubuntu settings but the built in scan software seems to ignore it. When xsane works, I can manually adjust the colour profile, and that works, but I'd rather use the built in software, since it seems that it's supposed to do what I'm asking. I've tried other scan utilities, xsane is the only one which seems to allow colour adjustment, but it's not reliable.

How do I get the scanner to use the colour calibration? Or how can I adjust something in the sane back end to adjust the blue cast by default?

I'm using up-to-date Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: I have the same problem. ET2750, simple-scan. There is a bug reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/simple-scan/+bug/1327801), not sure yet, if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

On my Epson ET-2750 under Ubuntu-MATE 21.04:

- When I start `imagescan` beforehand, brightness & contrast get obeyed.
- When I don't, brightness & contrast get ignored.

**For fun & illustration, this is my startup script for `scanlow` (also got one for `scanhigh`):**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
dconf write '/org/gnome/simple-scan/text-dpi' 75
dconf write '/org/gnome/simple-scan/photo-dpi' 75
dconf write '/org/gnome/simple-scan/jpeg-quality' 65

# a bit crisper
dconf write '/org/gnome/simple-scan/brightness' -30
dconf write '/org/gnome/simple-scan/contrast' 60

# multi scan delay (3 sec is too short)
dconf write '/org/gnome/simple-scan/page-delay' 6000

/usr/bin/imagescan &
simple-scan &
```

In all cases, contrast changes in simple-scan end up in the dconf registry, but only with imagescan called, some more specific scanner drivers are actived. (perhaps there is a more permanent way to do this in the background without opening the not required dialog?)